# increasing computing speed to find Constant Features across values

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm using the following code to find rows across columns that have all the same values. I'm using the following code and would like to increase computation speed since I have a very big dataframe and would like to do the same operation for other columns subsets:

```
dfSPSSstudent[dfSPSSstudent.loc[:,['Q4_1a_1', 'Q4_1a_2', 'Q4_1a_3', 'Q4_1a_4', 'Q4_1a_5', 'Q4_1a_6']].nunique(axis=1) ==1]
```

What would you recommend. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#generate sample data
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 5, (10**6, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=list("abcde"))
print(df.head())
```

It gives:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  4  0  3  3  3
1  1  3  2  4  0
2  0  4  2  1  0
3  1  1  0  1  4
4  3  0  3  0  2
```

Select rows where the columns `a`, `b` and `c` have equal values:

```
a = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy()
ddf = df[np.all(a == a[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)]
print(ddf.head())
```

It gives:

```
     a  b  c  d  e
 11  1  1  1  3  3
 21  3  3  3  2  3
 41  1  1  1  3  2
 52  1  1  1  1  2
137  2  2  2  3  2
```

The above code will omit rows where the columns `a`, `b` and `c` all have the `NaN` value. In order to include such rows in the results the code can be modified as follows:

```
a = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy()
ddf = df[(np.all(a == a[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)) |
         (df.loc[:, ['a', 'b', 'c']].isna().all(axis=1))]
```

Timing tests:

- the above code: 14.7 ms ± 358 µs
- the original code with `nunique()`: 5 s ± 291 ms